# Scala: Test out Inner function

Tags: scala, unit-testing

quite new to scala, hoping to get some help, if I have a method like this, how to test this prepareCappuccino method? Is there something like mokito.spy one this inner method? Thanks
http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/09/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-8-welcome-to-the-future.html

```
def prepareCappuccino(): Future[Cappuccino] = {
  def grind
  def heatWater
  def fronthMilk
  def brew
  // implementation of these methods above within this prepareCappuccino method
  for {
    ground <- grind("arabica beans")
    water <- heatWater(Water(20))
    foam <- frothMilk("milk")
    espresso <- brew(ground, water)
  } yield combine(espresso, foam)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have hardcoded the actual values you could simply test the expected ouput.

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val expected = Cappuccino(...)
val f = prepareCappuccino()
f.map(c => assert(c == expected))
```

Have a look at ScalaTest, Specs2 and ScalaCheck which are the established testing frameworks for scala. ScalaCheck gives you property based testing and choosing between the first two is just a matter of taste. Just pick one that you like more.

Handling of futures can be done via blocking (discouraged) or async testing. Here is a link to the ScalaTest docs regarding it: http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/async_testing

Please note that in "real code" you should avoid structuring your code in a way that complicates testing.